# How can I find the system time from the streaming api?

Tags: rest-api

I want the timestamp of "now" from SalesForce through the streaming or the rest api, for my client. It is important because I will use it for detecting changes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Neither API has a timestamp retrieval API, at least that I could find in the documentation. It shouldn't be necessary, either, but, if you really need the current server time, see the [SOAP API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm). salesforce.com supports all time zones, so it's not necessary to know what time it is unless the device you're programming for has no internal clock or that clock is unreliable. You could also just get the time from anywhere else, like a time server (NTP).